# Google Maps Controls not showing?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have this [site](http://bocado.launchlabs.asia/) and the google map controls are not showing? It shows a little part of it but not all of it. How am I going to fix this?

Side question: Look at the logo at the bottom of the map, when its clicked it shows a google info box. What I'd like to do is when it is clicked again, the info box would close. Any ideas on how to do this?

My googlemap Option

```
    var options = { 
  center : latlng, 
  scrollwheel :  false, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
  panControl: true, 
  zoomControl : true, 
  zoomControlOptions : 
    { 
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL, 
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT 
    },  
  mapTypeControl : true, 
  mapTypeControlOptions : 
    {  
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR, 
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT 
    }, 
  scaleControl : true, 
  scaleControlOptions : 
    { 
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT 
    }, 
  streetViewControl : true, 
  streetViewControlOptions : 
    { 
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT

    },
  panControl : false,  zoom : <?php echo $options['zoom'] ?>

};
```

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You have `panControl` defined as true and then as false but this is not the cause of problem. It seems that you have several dangling `<div>` and `</div>` tags which could cause problems. I suggest to check the file with some js validator. A hint: you are creating markers with map option defined and immediately after that map is set to null like `markerXY.setMap(null);`. That is completely unnecessary: just left out `map` option at marker definition and marker will not be shown until user decide.